# import decompiled apk source as android project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, apk, decompiling

The company doesn't have the source code of project I have been assigned.
Previously the project was build in cordova and I am an android studio person.

Thus, to get the source code I installed Apk Studio and have provided required binaries as shown:
[image]

I have successfully decompiled the apk as shown:
[image]

After decompiling I get folders as shown:
[image]

Now, I want this source in android studio.
I try to import this source as follows:
[image]

then
[image]

When I click finish, the project is imported but not as android project:
[image]

How to change this to android project.
Ultimate goal is to get the source of this cordova APK in android studio as android project.
So if you suggest any other decompiling technique, that will also do.

Comment: I see `smali`, then you need a decompiler that input `smali` and output `java` or so. What I mean is, your decompilation tour may go further than now.

Comment: Noticed that there is a "Decompile Java" in the second image , you may tick it first.